# Using Spring Session Redis without rdb snapshots

Tags: spring, redis, spring-session

Is there a need to have Redis snapshots when only using it as a session replication service with Spring Session? I read about Redis Persistence but it seems "persistence" only means backups, and that it is not fully required.

I have a problem in my application that no matter how many times I will call `FLUSHALL`, it will keep reloading old sessions somehow. I suspect from my RDB file.

Can I just define everything as memory only? Is there any reliability/performance benefits to use an RDB file at all?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem in my application that no matte how many times I will call FLUSHALL, it will keep reloading old sessions somehow. I suspect from my RDB file.

`FLUSHALL` will also remove data from RDB file. I think the data might be written by other processes after you called `FLUSHALL`.

> Can I just define everything as memory only?

Yes, you can disable saving db to disk with config file. By default, Redis will save data to disk with some save directives in the config file. For example:

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

To disable saving, just comment these save directives or add an empty save directive (i.e. `save ""`).

```
# save 900 1
# save 300 10
# save 60 10000
```

Also you can disable AOF persistence logs with config file:

```
appendonly no
```

> Is there any reliability/performance benefits to use an RDB file at all?

**Reliability**: Since Redis saves your data to disk, you can recover the data, when you restart Redis. However, if Redis is down accidently, you might lose some data, depends on your save directives in config file.

**Performance**: There's a performance penalty, especially when you are using RDB persistent with big data in memory.

You can get more details on **Redis Persistence** from [its website](http://redis.io/topics/persistence).

Comment: Thanks! Where is the documentation about flushall removing data from the file as well? Couldn't find it.

Comment: `flushall` deletes all keys of all of your databases. It must remove all data from the saved rdb file as well. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense to only remove data in memory, and there's no need a have a `flushall` command, right? You can do a test on a clean Redis instance.